# Ubuntu Mate, Bluetooth "Failed to connect device"

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mate

I am running Ubuntu Mate 15.10 on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm having a problem connecting my Ipazzport bluetooth keyboard. Ubuntu detects it but when I run setup I get "Failed to connect device" Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem with Apple Keyboard, have you found any solution?